# Add backslash if a string doesn't have it

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I'm developing a command line Batch file on Windows 7. I'm trying to add `\` to a dir if it hasn't.

This is only a test:

```
@echo off

set solutionDir=%CD%\

echo %solutionDir%

if [%solutionDir:~-1%] EQU [\] echo ends with \
```

This line `if [%solutionDir:~-1%] EQU [\] echo ends with \` works fine to check if it ends with `\` but I want to check if it doesn't end with a `\`.

I have tried all of these but in all of them I get a syntax error:

1. `if [%solutionDir:~-1%] NEQ [\] echo ends with \`
2. `if NOT [%solutionDir:~-1%]==[\] echo ends with \`
3. `if [%solutionDir:~-1%]!=[\] echo ends with \`

I'm getting current dir and I want to add it `\` if it hasn't it.

How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried: `if NOT [%solutionDir:~-1%] EQU [\] echo does not end with \ `

Comment: Added an answer so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `if [%solutionDir:~-1%] EQU [\] echo ends with \` works, the most logical thing to do is add a NOT clause after the if to make it do the opposite.

It would become:

```
if NOT [%solutionDir:~-1%] EQU [\] echo does not end with \
```